# char concat c++ no library functions

Tags: c++, char

How to concatenate two char* but without the library functions, I want to get a better insight on how this function works.
S1 = "AA"
S2 = "BB"

The function should return a pointer to "AABB";

This is the code I already have.

```
char *  concatenate(char * s1, char * s2)  
{  
    char * p = new char(string_length(s1) + string_length(s2) + 2);  
    return p ;  
}
int string_length(char * s)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And how does this not work?

Comment: Questions that may help you: Why add 2 to the character array you allocate in `concatenate`?  Now that you've made an array, what are you going to fill it with?  How would you tell a child to fill that array manually?

Comment: "I want to concatenate two char* but without the library functions" - Why?

Comment: You should always pass `char *` functions the max size of the string so they don't cause a crash.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: The question seems to be "What goes between `char * p = new...;` and `return p ;`?"

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I thought that the /0 of s1 and s2 took up space, my bad.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I want to get a better insight on how the library function works

Comment: @ChristianHackl changed it, was my first post ever, thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

1. Create a `char *` with the size of s1 + s2.
2. Loop through the first string and and each character.
3. Similarly fill the rest of the `char *` with the characters of the second string.
4. Add `\0` to indicate the termination of the character string.

*Also see all the comments on this post!*

```
size_t string_length(const char * s)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        ++i;

    return i;
}

char *  concatenate(const char * s1, const char * s2)
{
    size_t l1 = string_length(s1);
    size_t l2 = string_length(s2);

    /// Step 1:
    char * p = new char[l1 + l2 + 1];

    /// Step 2:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        p[i] = s1[i];
    }
    /// Step 3:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l2; i++) {
        p[i + l1] = s2[i];
    }

    /// Step 4:
    p[l1 + l2] = '\0';

    return p;
}


int main()
{

    char* test = concatenate("first", "second");
    cout << test;

    /// Delete after use.
    delete[] test;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in for loops `int` should be replaced with `size_t`. `:)`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm reasonably confident that smart pointers would qualify as library stuff.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe how about `size_t`?

Comment: size_t is just an implementation detail. A simple typedef with a semantic value but no additional functionality. I'd allow size_t under these artificial constraints.

Comment: Strings with no null terminator will crash.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two `char` strings there are a couple of design decisions to make.

The most crucial is whether you want the user of the concatenation function to provide their own memory area to hold the strings or do you want to provide a sufficiently large area yourself.

The nice thing about having the user provide the area is that the user can choose where the concatenated string will go and the user can decide how they are going to manage memory.

So lets create several related functions that will provide this capability and allow the user to decide how much or how little help they need.

```
template <typename T>
size_t Str_len(const T *s1)
{

    const T *const sStart = s1;
    if (s1)  while (*s1) s1++;    // guard against nullptr
    return s1 - sStart;
}

template <typename T>
T *Str_alloc(size_t nChars)
{
    T * p = new T[nChars + 1];    // plus 1 for end of string character

    p && nChars > 0 && (*p = 0);  // initialize new string with end of string if possible
    return p;
}

template <typename T>
void Str_delete(T *src)
{
    delete [] src;    // new array requires delete array
}

template <typename T>
T *Str_cpy(T *dest, const T *src)
{
    T * const destStart = dest;  // will return beginning of dest
    if (src && dest) {
        while (*dest++ = *src++);    // copy from src to dest including end of string
    }
    return destStart;
}

template <typename T>
T *Str_cat(T *dest, const T *src)
{
    if (src && dest) {
        T * const destStart = dest;  // will return beginning of dest
        while (*dest) dest++;     // find end of string of dest
        Str_cpy(dest, src);       // copy src to end of dest
        return destStart ;
    }
    else {
        return dest;  // bad args so just return dest
    }
}

template <typename T>
T *Str_cat_alloc(const T *s1, const T *s2)
{
    size_t nChars = Str_len(s1) + Str_len(s2);
    auto dest = Str_alloc <T> (nChars);
    if (dest && s1) {
        Str_cpy(dest, s1);
        if (s2) {
            Str_cat(dest, s2);
        }
        return dest;
    }
    else {
        return dest;
    }
}
```

and these would be used something like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    auto p1 = Str_alloc <char> (28);
    auto p2 = Str_alloc <char>(32);

    Str_cpy(p1, "this test");
    Str_cpy (p2, p1);
    Str_cat (p2, "xxx");

    auto p3 = Str_alloc <char> (Str_len(p1) + Str_len(p2));
    Str_cat (p3, p1);
    auto p4 = Str_cat (p3, p2);

    auto p5 = Str_cat_alloc("this is one ", "this is two");
    Str_delete (p1);
    Str_delete (p2);
    Str_delete(p3);
    // no delete on p4 as it is a copy of p3
    // see how confusing C style memory management can be?
    Str_delete(p5);

    return 0;
}
```

**Addendum: Using variadic templates**

Here is a further example using variadic templates which allows for variable number of arguments in a pleasant way. This example was compiled and somewhat tested using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

```
template <typename T>
T *Str_cat(T *a, const T * b)
{
    T *pSave = a;
    while (*a) a++;
    while (*a++ = *b++);
    return pSave;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T *Str_cat(T *a, const T *b, Args... args)
{
    T *pSave = a;
    while (*a) a++;
    for (; *a = *b; a++, b++);
    Str_cat(a, args...);

    return pSave;
}

template <typename T>
size_t Str_len(T *a)
{
    T *pSave = a;
    while (*a) a++;
    return a - pSave;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
size_t Str_len(T *a, Args... args)
{
    return Str_len(a) + Str_len(args...);
}
```

These functions can be used as follows.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv)
{
    char p[]  = "this is p1";
    char p2[] = "this is p2";
    char p3[] = "this is p3";
    char p4[] = "this is p4";
    char p5[] = "this is p5";
    char bigbuff[512];

    auto i = Str_len(p, p2, p3, p4);

    bigbuff[0] = 0;
    Str_cat(bigbuff, p, p2, p3);
    bigbuff[0] = 0;
    Str_cat(bigbuff, p, p2, p3, p4, p5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't remember seeing _TCHAR in the standard. I do agree on your C-style arguments, though I don't think it is what OP is shooting for.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe oops, my bad. Visual Studio 2013 strikes again.